# zeros of zeta function

Tags: riemann-zeta-function

Let $N(\sigma_{1}, \sigma_{2}; T)$ denote the number of
nontrivial zeros of the Riemann zeta-function
in the rectangle $1/2 \leq \sigma_{1} \leq \sigma_{2} < 1, 0 < Im(s) < T$.

If one could show that 
$N(\sigma_{1}, 1; T) \ll T$ for each $\sigma_{1} > 1/2$, then
would it follow that $N(1/2, 1/2; T) \sim (1/2\pi)T \log T$?

($N(1/2, 1/2; T)$ denotes the number of zeros on the segment $\sigma = 1/2$,
0 < Im(s) < T.)

Comment: Not quite, for silly reasons as literally given: the constant needn't be uniform, etc.

Comment: @paulgarrett I agree with your scepticism, but "follow" may be somehow different from "follow immediately".

Comment: @FedorPetrov : I guess an illustration is $\rho_{k} = 1/2 + e^{-k} + i\frac{ k \ln k}{2 \pi}$, it fulfills the requirements, everything is uniform, but the RH is 100% false. I saw those kind of sequences in [zeros of entire functions represented by Fourier transforms, Peter Hallum](http://math.hawaii.edu/home/theses/MA_2014_Hallum.pdf) trying to understand if functions close to $\xi(s)$ have their zeros on the critical line